# How to cut out a triangle in a circle button using Kotlin in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I'm going to design a layout which includes a circle button. There is a triangle in centre of the circle. The background of the circle should be transparent but the background of triangle should be the main background (in fact I wanna cut out a triangle from a circle button). Do you have any idea how to implement that using Kotlin?

image is attached:
[button image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRehJ.png)

Comment: I would create that in a vector art program like Illustrator or Inkscape and import it as a Vector Asset.

Comment: This could be a good idea but I think if I use this method and make the background transparent, the triangle will be transparent too

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind thay Android Studio doesn't have an image editor inside it. The easiest way to achieve it is getting the icon vector and importing it to android studio.

When It comes to design, there are some tools that helps devs. Take a look at this material icon database and search for "play":
https://materialdesignicons.com/
Download the SVG and import it to android studio.

An alternative is, inside android studio, right-click at res>drawable folder. Import Vector Asset. Android studio has some ready-to-use icons. You'll may find some there too.